# Bind a List to Data Grid View which contains Check Box Column

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I am having a hard time binding a list of objects to a data grid view which has check box columns.

The values do not show even when I identify the TrueValue, and the FalseValue.

Here is what I did

```
public class Tree{
  public bool Added{get;set;}
  public string TaskName{get;set;}
  }
```

in the form this is what the designer looks like

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn ClmnCheckBox;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ClmnName;
    this.DgvTrees.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 26);
    this.DgvTrees.MultiSelect = false;
    this.DgvTrees.Name = "DgvNoneTasks";
    this.DgvTrees.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    this.DgvTrees.SelectionMode =System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        this.DgvTrees.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(505, 145);
        this.DgvTrees.TabIndex = 27;
        this.DgvTrees.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.DgvTrees_CellContentClick);
        this.DgvTrees.CellValueChanged += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.DgvTrees_CellValueChanged);



       this.ClmnCheckBox.DataPropertyName = "Added";
        this.ClmnCheckBox.FalseValue = "false";
        this.ClmnCheckBox.HeaderText = "Add/Remove";
        this.ClmnCheckBox.Name = "ClmnCheckBox";
        this.ClmnCheckBox.TrueValue = "true";
        // 
        // ClmnName
        // 
        this.ClmnName.DataPropertyName = "TaskName";
        this.ClmnName.HeaderText = "Task Name";
        this.ClmnName.Name = "ClmnName";
        this.ClmnName.ReadOnly = true;
```

and this is how I bind the list to the grid

```
 var tree= new Tree(){
 Added=true,
 TaskName="task1"
 };
 ListOfTrees.Add(tree);
 DgvTrees.DataSource=ListOfTrees;
```

Now beyond that point, I get the record, but the checkbox is not checked. If I manually check it, it will get checked, but as soon as I refresh the grid, or sort it the check is gone. What could be causing this ?

Comment: Data binding only works on public properties -> make the class properties public

Comment: They are public I just didnt edit the question, the value gets reset to unchecked as soon as I apply a filter, or sort the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed by listening to the event RowsAdded, each time the row is added weather through sorting, or through filtering, I set the checkbox to objects boolean value